# How to define "to the best of your ability"?

Tags: harbour

The rules of Harbour state that when you move to a card you must carry out its action to the best of your ability. This raised some questions in our group during a recent game.

Take for example the card where you:

1. Exchange N of one good for N of another good, and
2. Buy a building.

In the situation where you have no goods, you can do neither. That makes sense.

In the situation where you have enough goods to fulfill enough orders to afford at least one building on the board, you must do both. That, too, makes sense.

The situation that's tricky to us is where I have some goods, but not enough to fulfill enough orders to afford any of the buildings.

Does the player moving to that card:

1. Do nothing?
2. Exchange N of one good for N of another good only?
3. Exchange N of one good for N of another good and fulfill as many orders as they can, even though they will lose their money since they can't afford any of the houses?

Which of these is considered "to the best of their ability"?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So from the rules for Actions;

> Some actions have two separate parts that are not dependent on each other and in those cases you may perform the parts in any order, or perform one part and not the other. However you must perform both actions if you can.

And for Buying.

> Taking a "buy a building" action is the only time you may ship goods.

While you do have to perform both actions, it is only if you can. The second action on the card is "buy a building" which you do by shipping goods to pay for it. If there is no building you can afford then you cannot take the buy a building action and do not have to ship any goods to pay for it. Shipping and buying are not separate actions, they cannot be performed separately.

There is also no concept of fulfilling "as many orders as you can". You ship as many or as few **types of good** as you need to purchase the relevant building. If you can meet the cost just shipping fish, there is no need or requirement to ship Wood, Meat or Stone at the same time.

Answer (score 3):

In the rules for Harbor, under "How Buildings Work":

> Some actions have two separate parts which are not dependent on each
>   other, and in those cases you may perform the parts in any order, or
>   perform one part and not the other.  However, you must perform both if
>   you can.  The actions with two separate parts are the Library, Bank,
>   Traders Guild, Architectural Society, Privateer Ship, and Seaside
>   Crane, and they all have the '&' symbol.

So in your case you would exchange goods and then end your turn.